# Content Type Column not appearing in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, content-type, site-column

I am adding a content type to a document library, but after deleting and readding one of its site columns, this column does not appear in the document library anymore. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose "yes" for "Update all content types inheriting from this type" when changing Content Type column.

[image]

Comment: that did not help me...